# Jittered values shown as if unjittered in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I hope anybody can help with this: In the below dataframe `df` (which is just a small snippet of the actual data) I want to plot `RelPosition` values in facets grouped by `size`. To avoid overplotting I thought I can use the function `jitter` so that the individual points spread out a little on the x-axis. But in actual fact `jitter` does not produce any effect, however I manipulate the `factor` argument. The resulting plot is the same as the plot with the unjittered `RelPosition` values. **What am I doing wrong?** (I've used pretty much the same code some time ago and it worked well!)

```
library(ggplot2)

df %>%
  # add some noise to `RelPosition`:
  mutate(RelPosition_0 = jitter(RelPosition, factor = 2.5)) %>%
  # plot:
  ggplot(aes(y = Turn_no, x = RelPosition_0, group = size)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  # make facets:
  facet_grid(size ~ ., scales = "free")
```

Plot:

[image]

Data:

```
df <- structure(list(Turn_no = c(165139L, 165139L, 466750L, 467001L, 
337803L, 337803L, 337976L, 337976L, 466320L, 338960L, 338960L, 
218992L, 92229L, 92229L, 92229L, 92088L, 92088L, 92088L, 3275L, 
3275L, 248241L, 518616L, 114382L, 114382L, 114382L, 3000L, 152386L, 
513337L, 513337L, 513337L, 228548L, 384589L, 384589L, 350381L, 
187257L, 187257L, 187257L, 443281L, 228906L, 228906L, 440928L, 
186368L, 186158L, 186158L, 186158L, 186158L, 444714L, 460969L, 
489197L, 17134L, 17134L, 17134L, 17134L, 17134L, 17134L, 17134L, 
17134L, 17134L, 323329L, 323329L, 492561L, 381702L, 257404L, 
341151L, 525229L, 525229L, 525229L, 525229L, 525229L, 525229L, 
525229L, 337294L, 337294L, 491769L, 74689L, 74689L, 154851L, 
372917L, 372917L, 372917L, 372945L, 222038L, 222038L, 222038L, 
271759L, 177344L, 177344L, 178194L, 149519L, 149519L, 149519L, 
149519L, 149519L, 28095L, 28095L, 480366L, 480366L, 480366L, 
480366L, 480366L, 480366L, 461072L, 461072L, 441398L, 441398L, 
363520L, 69097L, 69097L, 385120L, 385120L, 342664L, 31924L, 208178L, 
208178L, 403945L, 403945L, 403945L, 94913L, 94913L, 94913L, 163596L, 
89265L, 89265L, 107335L, 107335L, 126926L, 390832L, 390832L, 
390832L, 306140L, 345355L, 294521L, 66190L, 264129L, 264129L, 
319003L, 319003L, 518210L, 518210L, 304580L, 459838L, 459838L, 
478484L, 131754L, 131754L, 512974L, 269203L, 269202L, 371641L, 
260315L, 260315L, 231511L, 471023L, 471023L, 448694L, 63800L, 
435909L, 457706L, 457706L, 457706L, 457706L, 83336L, 29040L, 
29040L, 29040L, 29040L, 42127L, 42127L, 379374L, 32179L, 282836L, 
198708L, 198708L, 331173L, 331173L, 331173L, 131329L, 131329L, 
231576L, 231576L, 231576L, 514900L, 514900L, 514900L, 292332L, 
292332L, 292332L, 264248L, 275960L, 433118L, 423386L, 239883L, 
258959L, 258959L, 295063L, 481781L, 481781L, 481781L, 479161L, 
479161L, 281327L, 352160L, 149307L, 149307L, 229855L, 288947L, 
288947L, 236511L, 327584L, 10880L, 160662L, 402713L, 401846L, 
15L, 15L, 458562L, 29303L, 29303L, 29303L, 134428L, 186269L, 
99319L, 99319L, 99319L, 356666L, 228759L, 293359L, 76550L, 159983L, 
309425L, 309425L, 11054L, 493770L, 493770L, 493770L, 493771L, 
493771L, 51876L, 51876L, 30402L, 314145L, 243822L, 121421L, 121421L, 
121421L, 267051L, 18209L, 311926L, 311926L, 311926L, 311926L, 
311926L, 359709L, 89470L, 519080L, 420301L, 420301L, 420301L, 
420301L, 420301L, 8653L, 8653L, 523162L, 523162L, 346186L, 346186L, 
210719L, 427401L, 427401L, 368144L, 294769L, 294769L, 294769L, 
390456L, 390456L, 88680L, 384935L, 384935L, 384935L, 70917L, 
70917L, 232705L, 457495L, 425399L, 60068L, 29791L, 22563L, 22563L, 
519272L, 519272L, 138044L, 138044L, 192591L, 192591L, 192591L, 
464557L, 464557L, 464557L, 318702L, 318702L, 491766L, 491766L, 
491766L, 167344L, 167344L, 167344L, 81889L, 81889L, 81889L, 81889L, 
204513L, 204513L, 35177L, 35177L, 316339L, 316339L, 316339L, 
294570L, 294570L, 464603L, 464603L, 464603L, 427495L, 35089L, 
35089L, 35089L, 268041L, 268041L, 99908L, 99908L, 225916L, 225916L, 
225439L, 225439L, 140732L, 140732L, 385482L, 385482L, 385482L, 
135273L, 135273L, 147234L, 353246L, 353246L, 353246L, 385088L, 
220506L, 220506L, 220506L, 220506L, 480802L, 480802L, 452915L, 
118762L, 118762L, 519196L, 217055L, 291282L, 428886L, 56037L, 
376825L, 356839L, 356839L, 411092L, 46819L, 402301L, 402301L, 
357615L, 357615L, 187835L, 368624L, 139227L, 301997L, 290620L, 
185906L, 185906L, 253592L, 110866L, 110866L, 25277L, 25277L, 
50222L, 50222L, 50222L, 239742L, 93053L, 93053L, 473156L, 473156L, 
264052L, 282329L, 416984L, 106990L, 420785L, 304610L, 423294L, 
423294L, 423294L, 419152L, 138206L, 318646L, 318646L, 256703L, 
472987L, 472987L, 436470L, 436472L, 396101L, 52821L, 442261L, 
274765L, 449261L, 449261L, 449261L, 64251L, 64251L, 64251L, 268087L, 
493058L, 160888L, 160888L, 246499L, 154057L, 268135L, 268135L, 
268135L, 268135L, 396226L, 271448L, 53838L, 53838L, 53838L, 490337L, 
490337L, 363146L, 363146L, 495495L, 495495L, 454723L, 454723L, 
454723L, 476767L, 476767L, 24796L, 24796L, 24796L, 24796L, 24796L, 
462095L, 462095L, 462095L, 462095L, 398432L, 146610L, 146610L, 
146609L, 146609L, 146609L, 517721L, 517721L, 418453L, 418453L, 
324165L, 324165L, 207420L, 223765L, 223765L, 484901L, 372944L, 
63338L, 63338L, 63338L, 63338L, 63338L, 432331L, 432331L, 432331L, 
432331L, 138138L, 138138L, 220680L, 414866L, 360141L, 377889L, 
377889L, 377889L, 377889L, 377889L, 511377L, 511377L, 511377L, 
511377L, 106036L, 106036L, 403887L, 9243L, 377923L, 163776L, 
163776L, 163776L), RelPosition = c(0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.285714285714286, 1, 0.625, 0.75, 1, 0.294117647058824, 0.529411764705882, 
0.833333333333333, 0, 0.142857142857143, 0.857142857142857, 0, 
0.125, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.125, 1, 0.2, 0.266666666666667, 
0.466666666666667, 0.444444444444444, 1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.45, 1, 
0.136363636363636, 0.636363636363636, 1, 0.222222222222222, 0.555555555555556, 
1, 1, 0.833333333333333, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.5, 0.583333333333333, 0.75, 0.5, 1, 0.6, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.125, 0.208333333333333, 0.333333333333333, 0.458333333333333, 
0.75, 0.833333333333333, 0.875, 0.916666666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.666666666666667, 
0.5, 1, 1, 0.0869565217391304, 0.304347826086957, 0.391304347826087, 
0.565217391304348, 0.782608695652174, 0.91304347826087, 0.956521739130435, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 
0.916666666666667, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 
0.166666666666667, 0.25, 0.75, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.2, 0.6, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0909090909090909, 0.318181818181818, 0.681818181818182, 
0.727272727272727, 1, 0.142857142857143, 0.285714285714286, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.444444444444444, 0.666666666666667, 0.888888888888889, 
1, 0.05, 0.15, 0.25, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.0714285714285714, 
0.642857142857143, 0.111111111111111, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.4, 
0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 
1, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.142857142857143, 
0.857142857142857, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.125, 0.6875, 0.875, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0.153846153846154, 0.692307692307692, 0.333333333333333, 0.833333333333333, 
0.5, 1, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.222222222222222, 0.181818181818182, 0.818181818181818, 
0.4, 1, 0.5, 1, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.214285714285714, 0.571428571428571, 
1, 0.222222222222222, 1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.6, 1, 1, 0.19047619047619, 
0.285714285714286, 0.523809523809524, 0.80952380952381, 0.4, 
0.8, 1, 1, 1, 0.4, 1, 0.0769230769230769, 0.384615384615385, 
0.846153846153846, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.2, 
0.4, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 1, 
0.142857142857143, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0588235294117647, 0.5, 0.25, 1, 
0.25, 0.1, 0.8, 1, 0.125, 1, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.2, 1, 
0.25, 0.0909090909090909, 0.727272727272727, 0.25, 0.5, 0.111111111111111, 
0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.166666666666667, 
0.666666666666667, 0.5, 0.1, 0.5, 0.8, 0.5, 0.2, 0.2, 0.8, 1, 
0.5, 0.5, 0.25, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.1, 0.8, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.2, 0.8, 0.1, 1, 0.25, 
0.0833333333333333, 0.125, 0.111111111111111, 0.444444444444444, 
0.666666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 0.5, 0.0909090909090909, 
0.272727272727273, 0.363636363636364, 0.636363636363636, 1, 0.142857142857143, 
0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.0714285714285714, 0.357142857142857, 
0.714285714285714, 0.928571428571428, 1, 0.25, 1, 0.142857142857143, 
1, 0.0625, 0.375, 0.5, 0.125, 0.875, 0.25, 0.0909090909090909, 
0.545454545454545, 0.727272727272727, 0.25, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
0.25, 0.75, 1, 0.25, 0.75, 0.1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
0.25, 1, 0.1, 0.5, 0.7, 0.111111111111111, 0.444444444444444, 
0.888888888888889, 0.0588235294117647, 0.235294117647059, 0.142857142857143, 
0.571428571428571, 0.714285714285714, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 
1, 0.0909090909090909, 0.272727272727273, 0.545454545454545, 
0.636363636363636, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 1, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
0.5, 1, 0.25, 0.0526315789473684, 0.157894736842105, 0.789473684210526, 
0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.142857142857143, 0.571428571428571, 
0.333333333333333, 1, 0.142857142857143, 1, 0.125, 0.375, 0.142857142857143, 
0.428571428571429, 0.857142857142857, 0.2, 0.6, 0.25, 0.1, 0.3, 
1, 0.142857142857143, 0.05, 0.2, 0.7, 0.85, 0.2, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
0.333333333333333, 1, 0.25, 0.5, 0.5, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
0.166666666666667, 0.0625, 0.6875, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 1, 
0.2, 0.1, 0.125, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 0.25, 0.5, 0.142857142857143, 
0.0909090909090909, 0.909090909090909, 0.1, 0.2, 0.1, 0.4, 1, 
0.5, 0.25, 0.75, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.5, 0.5, 0.2, 0.0769230769230769, 
0.25, 0.333333333333333, 0.125, 0.625, 0.875, 0.5, 0.2, 0.142857142857143, 
0.571428571428571, 0.5, 0.2, 1, 0.5, 0.125, 1, 1, 1, 0.785714285714286, 
0.5, 0.75, 1, 0.0555555555555556, 0.388888888888889, 0.777777777777778, 
1, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 1, 0.0833333333333333, 0.25, 0.0666666666666667, 
0.133333333333333, 0.8, 0.866666666666667, 0.333333333333333, 
0.2, 0.333333333333333, 0.666666666666667, 1, 0.166666666666667, 
1, 0.2, 0.6, 0.166666666666667, 0.666666666666667, 0.1, 0.5, 
0.7, 0.5, 1, 0.0833333333333333, 0.25, 0.666666666666667, 0.833333333333333, 
1, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.666666666666667, 1, 1, 0.333333333333333, 
1, 0.0625, 0.4375, 0.5625, 0.166666666666667, 0.5, 0.333333333333333, 
1, 0.2, 1, 0.2, 0.1, 1, 0.333333333333333, 0.142857142857143, 
0.125, 0.375, 0.625, 0.875, 1, 0.0416666666666667, 0.0833333333333333, 
0.458333333333333, 0.625, 0.125, 0.375, 0.0909090909090909, 0.166666666666667, 
0.5, 0.0555555555555556, 0.388888888888889, 0.555555555555556, 
0.611111111111111, 0.833333333333333, 0.0909090909090909, 0.818181818181818, 
0.909090909090909, 1, 0.125, 0.75, 0.4, 1, 0.25, 0.0454545454545455, 
0.272727272727273, 0.545454545454545), size = c(7L, 7L, 19L, 
13L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 7L, 18L, 18L, 13L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
4L, 4L, 9L, 3L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 19L, 5L, 21L, 21L, 21L, 5L, 23L, 
23L, 3L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 3L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 
5L, 3L, 6L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 7L, 
7L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 24L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 13L, 13L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 
23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 23L, 8L, 8L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
21L, 21L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 15L, 15L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 15L, 15L, 6L, 6L, 10L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 10L, 12L, 
12L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 15L, 15L, 3L, 10L, 3L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 22L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 
6L, 14L, 14L, 14L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
8L, 3L, 3L, 18L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 
6L, 6L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 5L, 3L, 10L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 3L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 11L, 11L, 5L, 13L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 4L, 
3L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 8L, 5L, 4L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 15L, 
15L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 8L, 17L, 17L, 3L, 9L, 9L, 5L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
5L, 5L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 5L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 18L, 18L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 5L, 20L, 20L, 20L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 4L, 4L, 
8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 8L, 21L, 
21L, 21L, 21L, 6L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 7L, 17L, 
17L, 6L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 11L, 9L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 8L, 
12L, 12L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 
6L, 14L, 5L, 4L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 3L, 6L, 8L, 8L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 3L, 
9L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 15L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
13L, 5L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 16L, 7L, 6L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 
6L, 7L, 7L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 3L, 3L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 13L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 17L, 17L, 17L, 7L, 7L, 4L, 4L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 11L, 11L, 4L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 25L, 
9L, 9L, 12L, 7L, 3L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 19L, 12L, 12L, 12L, 
12L, 9L, 9L, 6L, 3L, 5L, 23L, 23L, 23L)), row.names = c(NA, -500L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of jitter you have specified via `factor` is simply too small to be visible. According to the docs the `amount` of jitter is computed as:

> factor * d/5 where d is about the smallest difference between x values.

I think it's easier to set the amount of jitter directly via the `amount` parameter, e.g. using `amount=.01`:

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.3.1

df |>
  transform(
    RelPosition_0 = jitter(RelPosition, amount = .01)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = RelPosition, x = RelPosition_0)) +
  geom_point(alpha = 0.5)
```

[image]

```r
df |>
  transform(
    RelPosition_0 = jitter(RelPosition, amount = .01)
  ) |>
  ggplot(aes(y = Turn_no, x = RelPosition_0)) +
  geom_point(size = 2, alpha = 0.5) +
  # make facets:
  facet_grid(size ~ ., scales = "free")
```

[image]